# Field type TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete this field.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, taxonomy, field-type

SharePoint Foundation 2013, when I click on Site Settings->Site Columns I receive the error. I ran a powershell script located [here](https://saiayasharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/field-type-is-not-installed-properly-go-to-the-list-settings-page-to-delete-this-field/)

and got a list of potential damaged lists and their ids. went through, thought I found the bad field, deleted the list itself (note being used) but still no luck trying to view columns. I receive that error above. I have gone through manually(a real pain) all of the lists and libraries for all of the subsites trying to find another bad field, without success. Anyone run into this issue before and was able to solve it?

Comment: are you trying to create a taxonomy field ?

Comment: No, actually trying to find a taxonomy field that must have come over from an enterprise environment years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this problem... especially if you cannot find the field in question. See this article for the answer.

[Corrupted Site Columns SP 2010](https://jshidell.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/removing-a-corrupted-site-column-in-sharepoint-2010/)